# Image is not displayed/loaded in my django website which i deployed on Cpanel

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, cpanel

`details of my code, in my settings.py i have:`

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

and this is how i tried to acces form the template:
in very first page:

```
% load static %
```

to display image,

```
 <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/main.png' %}" alt="imagetwo" width="100" height="50"></a>
```

anyone who can help me, please

`if you need further details of the project structure, from cpanel root, mainfolder/users. users is my app. mainfolder/mydjango mydjango is my dajngo project, both django project and app is at the same directory level! The image is found in mainfolder/users/static/images/`

Answer (score 0):

You have just try load image Like,

Your code:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static 'images/main.png' %}" alt="imagetwo" width="100" height="50"></a>
```

Try My Answer:

```
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="{% static '/images/main.png' %}" alt="imagetwo" width="100" height="50"></a>
```

Follow my code, to load your images just put `/` before your folder name and after write your image name.

Answer (score 0):

coul've forgoten to add this :

```
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

to the url.py file